# How to load database before init ChangeNotifierProvider?

Tags: flutter

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  void initState() {
    onStart();// it is 'Future<void> onStart() async', it will load database from sqlite
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<HostModel>(create: (context) => HostModel(), lazy: true),
          //this provider depend on onStart() loaded data, so it need to be execute after onStart()
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'Infinite List Sample',
            home: null
        ));
  }
}
```

`MyApp` is the first widget in my flutter program. It need to load config data from the sqlite, and then use these data to init provider. But it seem always init the provider before the `onStart()` function complete, so it cause error.

I have try the `futureBuilder`, but load data is very quickly (<100ms), so `futureBuilder` only will produce a 100ms splash screen, it is just a useless flash page.

I also consider the futureProvider, but it seem it can not solve the problem.

I don't know what is a good method to process such problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the initial config method in the main function as

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //call the initial config method
  await onStart();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: It seem change `onStart()` to `await onStart()` would be better.